# Trouble when parsing JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, django

I'm dumping JSON in Django view and then parsing JSON in JS to get the data.

My view.py (Django)

```
ibms = []
for i in range(2, 5):
    ibm = Mapa(i, wsMapa)
    ibms.append(ibm.__dict__)
ibms = json.dumps(ibms)

return render(request, 'mapas/index.html', {'ibms': ibms})
```

The `ibm` variable output in Django template is:

```
[{"numeroIbm": "AUTO P"}, {"numeroIbm": "PTB"}, {"numeroIbm": "FAROL"}]
```

My index.html (JS inside)

```
{{ ibms|json_script:"ibms" }}
<script>
    const mydata = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("ibms").textContent);
    const mydata2 = JSON.parse(mydata);
</script>
```

The issue is: I'm having to `JSON.parse` double times to get the JS object. The variable `mydata`, despite the `JSON.parse`, is string typeof. I only get the final result when I `JSON.parse` for the second time (`mydata2`).

What is happening, pls?

Tks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not dump it in the view, so:

```
ibms = [Mapa(i, wsMapa).__dict__ for i in range(2, 5)]

return render(request, 'mapas/index.html', {'ibms': ibms})
```

and thus parse it as:

```
{{ ibms|json_script:"ibms" }}
<script>
    const mydata = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("ibms").textContent);
    // no second parse
</script>
```

Comment: Tks a lot! It worked!! I run again the code printing in Django view 2 different versions: the data structure seems the same, except for the double quotes when dumping the code and with single quotes without dumping. That is the problem?

Comment: @FelipeDourado: what you did was dumping a *string*, so that is why it was surrounded by double quotes (and likely the quotes inside were escaped).